# Remove "submitted by"

Tags: theming

How can I remove "submitted by"? I already try to remove it on admin/structure/types/manage/page, but i still see "Submitted by...".

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you using a custom theme, any Views, or anything like that? Core Drupal definitely respects this setting as well as any of the base themes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check your node and page level twig templates to make sure it is not outputting the submitted by information, despite what the setting is here. There could also be a Views block outputting this information in one of the regions, which would ignore the setting as well.

Comment: i remove from the templates file. But still dosent work.

Comment: I try to remove all dates from  the cache and i resolved